# Should I shard all collections in my MongoDB or just some

Tags: mongodb

I am running MongoDB cluster (backend to my website). I am converting my previous DB from being plain into sharded  structure.

Question is: should I shard all my collections or only those that I expect to grow a lot. I have some collections that will never get bigger than a few thousands documents, few hundred thousands at most, should I shard them anyway? If yes when? Right now during conversion or convert it without shading and shard later?

To rephrase the question : if a table is not too big, are there any benefits for it to be sharded?

Answer (score 1):

A common misconception is that sharding is based upon the size of a collection. This is totally untrue. It is however, true that common sense dictates that when a collection reaches a certain size it is possibly too much to store on a single server, but on the other hand the cause to shard is decided by operations not size.

It makes sense that those that will "grow a lot" should be sharded to distribute those operations within a cluster however those that might be a lot quieter, such as your smaller collections can happily remain on the primary shard.

As to when to shard them: that depends on the operations. Sharding is designed to scale out reads and writes so it is merely a question of when a collection needs to be scaled out.

You could have a collection of maybe a 1,000 items but if the operations call for it to be sharded then it needs sharding. Vice versa you could have a collection of 1 billion items and it still doesn't merit sharding.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what is "OP" and how do I know that "OPs call for it to be sharded"?

Comment: @henry sorry it is short for operations, like reads/writes/etc

Comment: @henry the second point is kinda hard and it is the key to sharding. I would say there are a couple of ways to tell: 1. would be IO bottle neck resulting from operations on that collection (mongostat can tell you this stuff) another could be that reads are slow on this collection despite it being as optimised as possible on a single server